# Click image in datalist

Tags: asp.net, image, datalist

I have images in datalist which i get from database. I want to be able to click on an image which would than take me to a new page where the image would be displayed and the information about image would be displayed too.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("ViewProductDetail.aspx?Image={0}", Eval("Picture")) %>' runat="server">

        &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="127px" 
                ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Picture", "~/Image/{0}") %>' Width="129px" />

                </asp:HyperLink>

                <br />
        <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:C}") %>' />
```

so what do i have to code for ViewProductDetail.aspx to retrieve the information of the images i click?

Comment: What code do you have in the ViewProductDetail.aspx page? What have you tried? Also, I think ASP.NET would be a more useful tag for this than 'image', at least add the ASP.NET tag.

Comment: er currently its empty ><
looking for some guidance what i should do..

Answer (score 1):

Try This
Add ProdcutId in query string according this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnk" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("ViewProductDetail.aspx?ProductId={0}", Eval("productid")) %>' runat="server">

    &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="127px" 
            ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Picture", "~/Image/{0}") %>' Width="129px" />

   </asp:HyperLink>
```

in ViewProductDetail.aspx page load event get ProductId Value from Query string

```
if(Request.Querystring["ProductId"] !=null && Request.Querystring["ProductId"] !="")
{
  //get product details from product id and show on page
}
```